# Parsing percent values from string in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, model, finance

I am currently working on a financial model where each team receives different types of news such as this :

> 1,379,BondD,News regarding Dayaria Milk Products,Dayaria Milk
>   Products' sales increase by 25% in comparison to an analyst consensus
>   of 23%. The market is currently questionning whether it is due to an
>   increase in sales of organic milk given the health trends, or due to
>   the temporary increase in prices after the shortage in North America.

P.S. I didn't make the names.

Since this is a sales increase and it contains a percent sign increase, but only one of the % values actually matters.

I already have a parsing function that pulls for words such as 'increase' and 'decrease' but I haven't been able to figure out how I should go about differentiating % values that are useful and ignoring the ones that not.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me or show me where to start site. If you have code that is not working please put it in the original post using edit and explain where it is causing the error. If not this will probably be down voted and closed as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

if the increase or decrease percentage always follows those words then use the instr function to first find the word and then again to find the following % sign.

```
longNumber1 = instr(1,textVariable,"increase")
longNumber2 = instr(1,longNumber1, textVariable, "%") - 3
stringVariable = mid(textVariable,longNumber2, 3)
```